# Reshaping the current dataframe into another dataframe and creating new columns (concatenate)

Tags: r, reshape

I have the attached dataframe ([here](https://medcornell-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mmr2011_med_cornell_edu/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=k1gk4zO1pWGqduY%2Bobfhbwl192XjiaXz8N2l%2F%2FGLyus%3D&docid=2_174e1c676dec04e84959f157779c2e0ba&rev=1)) and I need to reshape it to be in the format shown below
[image]

Basically, I want to add each compare each traet group (LA, RA, BiA) to NP treat group and create a column that is concatenate between Studlab and treat arm.

I tried to figure this out using my prior answered question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626642/i-want-to-reshape-the-current-dataframe-with-some-empty-cells-into-another-dat)) but I could not.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: look into `reshape`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for follow up. I read reshape package but could not figure it out yet. so I am doing it manually in excel and it is time consuming. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you without a data sample and without knowing exactly where 2Total and Group2.event is comming from. But the basis should be somthing like:

```
df %>% 
 gather(treat2:treat4, key = "key", value = "tmp_compare_groupe") %>% 
 mutate(Compare_Groups = paste0("NP_", tmp_compare_groupe), 
        2nd.Total = case_when(tmp_compare_groupe == "LA" ~ LA,
                              tmp_compare_groupe == "RA" ~ RA,
                              tmp_compare_groupe == "BIA" ~ BIA,
                               ))
```

I don't know where Group2.event is comming from. After you have calculated all columns you have to select the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks for your providing this code. Dataframe is already attached as hyperlink in the 1st line of the post. Appreciate.